# How to check parameters of function called by apply | call | bind and infer the result type?

Tags: typescript

There is a function like this, it just calls "apply" and returns the result.
Is there a way to check the **args** parameter and infer the type of **result**?

```
function callFunc(func: Function, that: Object, args: any[] = []) {
  const r= func.apply(that, args);
  return r;
}

function t(a: number, b: number):number {
  return a + b;
}

const result = callFunc(t, {}, [1, 2]);
```

I tried some, but all have deficiencies.

1 Can't find too many parameters.

```
function callFunc<T extends Function, U extends any[], V>(func: (...args: U) => V, that: object, args: U): V {
  return func.apply(that, args);
}

callFunc(t, {}, [1, 2]); // Ok
callFunc(t, {}, [1, '2']); // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
callFunc(t, {}, [1, 2, 3]); // Expect an error, but no error.
```

2 Works, but there are errors on generic U and V.

```
// Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
function callFunc<T extends Function, U extends Parameters<T>, V extends ReturnType<T>>(func: T, that: Object, args: U): V {
  const r= func.apply(that, args);
  return r;
}

callFunc(t, {}, [1, 2]); // Ok
callFunc(t, {}, [1, '2']); // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
callFunc(t, {}, [1, 2, 3]); // Argument of type '[number, number, number]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number]'.
```

3 Works, but it's ugly.

```
function callFunc<T, U>(func: Function, that: object, args: T):U {
  return func.apply(that, args);
}

callFunc<Parameters<typeof t>, ReturnType<typeof t>>(t, {}, [1, 2]); // Ok
callFunc<Parameters<typeof t>, ReturnType<typeof t>>(t, {}, [1, '2']); // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
callFunc<Parameters<typeof t>, ReturnType<typeof t>>(t, {}, [1, 2, 3]); // Argument of type '[number, number, number]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>` seems to work just fine:

```js
function callFunc<T extends (...args: any) => any>(func: T, that: Object, args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> {
  const r= func.apply(that, args);
  return r;
}

function t(a: number, b: number):number {
  return a + b;
}

const result1 = callFunc(t, {}, [1, 2]);
const result2 = callFunc(t, {}, [1, "2"]); // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
const result2 = callFunc(t, {}, [1, 2, 3]); // Argument of type '[number, number, number]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number]'.
```

`strictBindCallApply` is configuration option is set to `true`. This is playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=150&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQMXBAPAFUQFMAPKIsAEwGdEAKAOiZQCcBzagLkRTAE8AlIgC8APh79RdUJG74ANIigALFFG4B5AEYArItEWsO3AAqsUAWyLkW1AqIHcAStZAsw%20PgAci9xAG8AWAAoRGQEaihEFmFEGQgGFC8vND46FTVDdmoBAG4QsJZXd2j84IBfEJD42AQlOhRuMBALLSIWRS0mlraWR2bW9oCC6OKkFEQAakQtMsrgkIgIqKLqEDQoAEYRZHQsHHTFf3LFAG1NxQAmAF08xeXRtY3LndQMbEhDgJPEc8UAIku-1uuUQAHowYhPD5EABySIsGBgNiwxAwWhgOBRFDUagwNhgFBaNBEJRwJTeUmwga9WEMe5gSKPdZQF6xN77T5QI4-P6IS6KADMIPBkIAguwWhQonBgBSYbDTjT2oplR1EGrrqj0RqsTxcfjCcTSVByV5zFYbIhZfKqUqeiqNQ6WFqGEA).